# Number of Complete or Full Binary Search Tree

Tags: binary-search-tree

We have keys 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 that are inserted in some order into an empty binary search tree, using basic insert algorithm for binary search tree. After inserting these keys, it results in a complete or full binary search tree. How many full or complete binary search trees can be constructed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the *shape* of a binary tree is fixed, there is only one way the (unique) keys can be assigned to the nodes of that tree for it to be a valid BST. We can see this from the fact that the in-order traversal of a BST generates the keys in sorted order.

So, let's count the number of shapes for a tree with 7 nodes.

- Complete binary tree: 1

  ```
       4
     /   \
    2     6
   / \   / \
  1   3 5   7
  ```

  This is also a full binary tree.
- Other full binary trees (all internal nodes have 2 children -- the maximum height is 4)

  ```
        6          6          2          2       
       / \        / \        / \        / \
      4   7      2   7      1   6      1   4
     / \        / \            / \        / \
    2   5      1   4          4   7      3   6 
   / \            / \        / \            / \
  1   3          3   5      3   5          5   7
  ```

  If we reduce the required height by one, we get the complete binary tree that was already counted.

So the total is 5.